# local / vpn pages via Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, vpn

If I'm looking for a local/intranet address while connect to a VPN, it works in safari or firefox but many times it will not work via google chrome

example address:
http://help/userui/ticket?ID=14273

Google Chrome takes me to a verizon page like so: "http://searchassist.verizon.com/main?ParticipantID=euekiz39ksg8nwp7iqj2fp5wzfwi5q76&FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fhelp%2Fuserui%2Fticket%3FID%3D14273&FailureMode=1&Implementation=&AddInType=4&Version=pywr1.0&ClientLocation=us"

How can I get chrome to realize that I'm looking for a page on an intranet on not to the public web?

Notes:

- Using Cisco AnyConnect as VPN client
- Chrome version 48.0.2564.97 (64-bit)
- OSX 10.11.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found on OSX so far is to use Safari which is better about detecting VPN pages.

Soon after you've navigated the pages Chrome starts to work as well. This must either be a DNS or caching issue, possible both (I'm no IT master).